# How does boost::remove_pointer work?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

So remove_reference or remove_pointer always return the primitive type.

I know that they use so called template specialization to do that in the template meta-programming, but I don't quite understand how.

For example below.

```
template<class T>
struct AAA
{
    typedef T Type;
};

template<class T>
struct AAA<T*>
{
    // Why does T become int, not int * all of sudden?
    // How come does this get rid of '*' in a specific way?
    typedef T Type;
};

int main()
{
    AAA<int *>::Type MyVar = 3; // MyVar is not a pointer!
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously I'm missing something, or some designated rules in using template, and I can't find any good articles that explain this well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: What does `T` need to be in the second specialization so that `T*` matches `int*`?

Comment: @GManNickG I just fixed that. Sorry to have written a mistake.

Comment: Sorry, didn't even see that typo. That's not what I meant. I mean fill in the `T` in the question I gave you to see how the logic in C++ works. For `T*` to match `int*`, `T` needs to be `int`. That's why `T` is `int` in the second specialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Why does T become int, not int * all of sudden?
```

`T*` is `int*`, so `T` must be `int`.